# Exportação excel usando JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber como faço uma função que exporte uma tabela para excel porem que não mostre certas colunas definidas com um class

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse plugin jQuery: http://papaparse.com/

Comment: Dei uma olhada, mas pelo que pude ver não tem a opção de **não mostrar certas colunas**

Comment: Certo, pra fazer isso você terá que criar um algoritmo para capturar os valores da tabela e ir povoando um JSON com esses valores, ignorando as colunas desejadas. Aí então você converte o JSON em .CSV utilizando o plugin. (depois eu posto um exemplo de código)